# Question about uefi secure boot and GPU

Tags: drivers, uefi

I have installed Nvidia drivers for my graphics card,but when I have secure boot enabled and go to `system settings -> Details` it says that my graphics card is `Intel® HD Graphics 620`.
so I try to switch it using `NVIDIA X server settings` but after I go to check whether  it changed `system settings` won't open.

I tried to do the same in secure boot disabled mode and `system settings` did open and said that my GPU was indeed Nvidia GTX 940MX. Also when I go to `NVIDIA X server settings` it shows more options than it did with enabled secure boot. so I thought I would leave secure boot disabled but I discovered a problem that I can't open steam.

So my question is: when I have secure boot enabled and switch graphics card in `NVIDIA X server settings` without rebooting, does it actually switch my graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

You can always confirm which graphics card is being used with: `prime-select query`.

You can change to Intel iGPU using:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Then change back to GTX 940M using:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

But in both cases you have to reboot for the changes to take effect and the other Graphics to be used.

Comment: But when I reboot, after I change to nvidia, it switches back to Intel.